# Is a dependency registered as .InstancePerRequest() in autofac always available in an asynchronous continuation?

Tags: c#, autofac

In an Autofac config: I have registered a dependency to be `.InstancePerRequest()` 
and have part of my code that is either using the `async` keyword or `.continueWith()`. My question is: if the dependency is used in a continuation that is executed asynchronously, will the dependency only be disposed once the async code has been executed or could it happen before?

Specific scenario:

```
     // in IocConfig.cs
     ContainerBuilder.Register(c => Context.CreateFromToken(                                                                     
       c.Resolve<IUser>().Name,                                                                                                                      
      .As<Context>()
      .InstancePerRequest();
```

Then in one file I have this code:

```
    // elsewhere in the code for a specific request..
    client.PostAsync(new Uri(_context.GetSetting("SomeEndpoint")),requestContent)
    .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            ErrorLog.Write(_context.CreateErrorEntry($"Request: sent {task.Result.StatusCode} result: {task.Result.ToJson()}", LogLevel.Debug));
        });
```

Will the `_context` here (which is `.InstancePerRequest()`) still be available in the `.ContinueWith()`, or can it be disposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same `HttpContext` (in MVC) or inbound `RequestMessage` (in Web API) is available in the continuation, then the per-request item will be there. The request lifetime scope is stored in those respective spots.

If it's not available (e.g., if your awaiter doesn't propagate the complete execution context) then the request lifetime scope will potentially get disposed out from under you and it won't be available.